# Unexpected end of stream when using Postman

Tags: c#, api, parsing, request, postman

I tried to make a http request using postman. But I am having a response of

> "Unable to determine boundary: unexpected end of stream".

[image]

When I checked from the server side, Looks like the request body is incomplete.
[image]

Any idea would greatly help.

Comment: That specific error message seems to exist only in this [library](https://github.com/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser/blob/develop/Source/HttpMultipartParser/StreamingMultipartFormDataParser.cs#L299) and if that is indeed what you're using it suggests the incoming data is corrupt. Do you have the same problem when using a 10kb pdf? Postman has a console view (bottom bar) that shows you the raw bytes that went on wire. Is that complete? If you're using that library how /where is it hosted? IIS? HttpListener? Something else?

Comment: Hi @rene, thanks for your reply. Yes, that's the library I am using, I tried another file but still receiving the same issue. I check the request in postman console, and the files was marked undefined. "file: undefined". It is hosted in HttpListener.